# XAMPP terminating worker thread 0

Tags: php, xampp

Am running PHP applications using XAMPP server in Windows XP. It was working fine just yesterday, but suddenly it started showing the error: "Terminating worker thread 0 and Terminating worker thread 1". Does anybody know what went wrong? Can you suggest the steps I have to do to fix it? 
My cmd prompt is also disappearing when I open it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means you have another web server open.... 
In my case when I faced that issue, I had the Skype opened using port 80. 
To solve this issue, you can try closing Skype and try or go to Skype settings, connection, and disable the checkbox that says: "Use port 80 and 443 as an alternatives for incoming connections"  See this thread: http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/12/03/disable-skype-from-using-opening-and-listening-on-port-80-and-443-on-local-computer/

Answer (score 1):

Click the button on the xampp control panel "check ports",
this will show you whats running through port 80, the same port that apache uses by default. I had Skype running through port 80 as soon as I quite Skype apache ran normally.

Thanks

Comment: I see Port80 is process :system, and I don't open skype!! how to solve this??

Answer (score 1):

Find this file in your apache conf folder : httpd-vhosts
Check this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
    Allowoverride All
    order deny,allow
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

maybe you have wrong code here ;) This is corect code in my file